# Autocall a button click at specified time in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a buttonclick event in C# that reads a text file.
I want to autocall this buttonclick so that it executes each day automatically at say 9PM.
How do I write a code for this?

Comment: Does your app run 24/7? Have you considered putting the code into a separate application (without a button to click) that can be run as a Windows Scheduled Task? It's much easier to run at a certain time each day that way. Please edit your question and add more details. (And a button click event can be called in code the same way as any other method, without having the button involved in any way, as long as your code doesn't access the sender or eventargs.)

Comment: You could create a Javascript clock and have it call the button click method when it is 9PM

Comment: @tuckerjt07: This question is about `C#` and `asp.net`. How in the world do you get `create a Javascript clock`? What does `JavaScript` have to do with anything?

Comment: @KenWhite (you probably should convert your "use Scheduled task" comment in answer) On JavaScript - it is actually not insane suggestion - since it is ASP.Net there is some HTML page with button that clicked and sends request to server. Keeping the page open 24/7 with timer that will trigger click via script is an option. If OP does not have permissions to setup scheduled tasks on server (or at least on client) it may be only sane option.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: A timer would be a better option than Javascript, but neither of them applies unless the app is running when the time occurs, and the poster hasn't answered that question yet. I'd gladly post an answer about the scheduled task, but that isn't the question that was asked here. If the poster wants more info about that, I'll post one. Thanks, though.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That is exactly what I was thinking as far as if the OP did not have the necessary permissions to run scheduled tasks on the server. Even if he does have the necessary permissions I still view the JS approach as a viable option.

Comment: Task scheduler does not help if THE asp.net app need to read the text file.  Does read perform other tasks or do you just need recent data?

Answer (score 1):

You could transfer the reading of the text file to be on the page load event, then just have a scheduled task program that accesses that link at the certain time of the day, so then the text file is read whenever you set it.